# Problem with PDF Controller in vTiger CRM 6.5

Tags: php, pdf, vtiger, vtigercrm

I work on one project, users actively use PDF templates in CRM, the fact is that I need to get the field value in the SalesOrderPDFContoller.php file: I used this code:`$this->focusColumnValue('input_name')`; So I should get the value from the Products module, but instead of the value i get 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->focusColumnValue() is used to get Salesorder field value not Product value.

If you know the Product id you can use :

$recordModel = Vtiger_Record_Model::getInstanceById($id, 'Product');

$your_input = $recordModel->get('input_name') ;

Comment: Jeremy,thanks for answering my question,i'm a newbie in Vtiger, how can i get the product id in SalesOrderPDFController.php  when i export record in PDF in SalesOrder module?

Comment: I think you can call the function loadRecord like this :

**$this->loadRecord($id);** (where $id is the SalesOrder id)

And then Products id related to SaleOrder will be available in **$this->associated_products** variable